# How to replace a word with in s specific line

Tags: livecode

position (a variable)  contain position of line
eg: line 3 of field 1.
I want to replace the word in that purticular position only.
I need this code for regular replacement.
replace "bad" with "good" in field "MytextField" 
But its work in all lines.
I need to replace in that 3rd line only. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

In LiveCode you can use chunk expressions to refer to any substring. So just use the replace command in conjunction with a text chunk expression:

```
replace "bad" with "good" in line 3 of field 1
```